# php ошибки xmlreader, как обработать и убрать?

Tags: php, xml

Есть обработчик xml файлов, работает через php new xmlreader(). Дак вот, есть проблема, пользователи частенько заливают левые кривые файлы, часто возникают ошибки warning. Они не отлавливаются try () catch () а пишутся в лог. заваливая лог. хочется чтобы в лог это не писалось, а корректно обрабатывалось.

скажите как можно обработать, если файл не корректный, определить это и выдать результат мол xml некорректный...

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.xmlreader.php

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: set error handler это я знаю, может есть какое то решение встроенное в xmlreader?